# Register a custom symfony console command to be available in the list of "suggested commands"

Tags: php, symfony4

Is it possible that a custom command can be registered in the symfony "suggested" command list?

For example, My OWN COMMAND in Symfony 4:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

class AppDoctrineFixturesLoadCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:doctrine-fixtures-load')
            ->setDescription('Drop/Create Database and load Fixtures ....')
            ->setHelp('This command allows you to load dummy data by recreating database and loading fixtures...');
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And that the "app:doctrine-fixtures-load" command be available in the list of suggested commands.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: what tool are you using to see these command hints?

Comment: It looks like a question you should ask to whoever made the Symfony plugin for your IDE (or whatever is displayed in your screenshot).

Comment: @Chausser The command tool shown in the image is from PHPStorm.

Comment: @NicolasB, I think the same, but when I installed the bundle "DoctrineFixturesBundle" its commands were added automatically and now are available from the command line as hints. That is a very useful feature because in the same way, we can register our commands in the symfony console instead of having to memorize them. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: @EdgarAlfonso I think it's not DoctrineFixturesBundle that registers its command line hints, but your PhpStorm Symfony plugin that knows DoctrineFixturesBundle's commands because DoctrineFixturesBundle is a very common Symfony bundle. Check [this page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Symfony2+Command+Line+Tool+Integration+-+Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm), it mentions how "other commands may be added by bundles that are installed in our application", so you need to add those commands to PhpStorm bundles for it to recognize them.